# Domino Server Incoming Mail Mime Encoding

Tags: smtp, ibm-domino, utf-8

I recently installed FP10 to the Domino 9 server and made changes to http.cnf to `AddType image/svg+xml .svg` 
I am not running IHS.  Incoming mail however now has encoded Subject:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?Breaking_News_-_LeBron:_Trump_is_u?= =?UTF-8?Q?sing_sports_to_=E2=80=98divide=E2=80=99_the_country?=
```

This only happens to some incoming messages.  What has happened?  Did I change something else, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install interim fix 1 or 2 as this fixes the bug.

Comment: That did it.  FP10 was fine until I added the extra SVG+XML to http.cnf.  This is the only occurrence out of several servers running FP10.  Thanks.